# Using docsify css in Markdown of VScode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, markdown, docsify

I'd like to use docsify to build my blog, and I use the VScode to manage my markwown files.

I want to have a preview of my blog, and I noticed that `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify@4/lib/themes/vue.css">` in docsify's `index.html`, so I just the this item `"markdown.styles:["https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify@4/lib/themes/vue.css"]` to VScode's `setting.json`.

The css worked, but I can't scroll the preview in VScode

Answer (score 0):

I also work with Docsify in VS Code for some of my projects. Mostly, I use the `serve docs` command to preview in a browser.
I have also installed a VS Code extension to preview files directly in VS Code called **docsify-preview**. I'm not sure if that can help you with what you are trying to do. It adds a *docsify preview* icon next to the usual preview icon so you can check quickly the page you are working on, including the navigation between the pages.

[image]